# Let $G$ be a group of order $pq$, where $p<q$ and $p$,$q$ are primes. Let $Q$ be a q-Sylow and $P_1$ , $P_2$ be distincts p-Sylow.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Show that

a) Given $h_1, h_2 \in Q$ distincts, then $h_1 P_1 h_1^{-1} \neq h_2 P_1 h_2^{-1}$.

b) There is $h \in Q$ such that $h P_1 h^{-1} = P_2.$

I do not know how to do this. All I did about Sylow's theorems was to prove the existence of normal subgroups. 
Any help would be nice.

**@Edit:**

b) Since $n_p | q$ and $P_1, P_2$ are two distincts p-sylow we have that $n_p = q.$ If for all $h \in Q$ $h P_1 h^{-1} \neq P_2$ we would have, since $\#Q = q$ ,  $n_p > q$, contradiction. (by a) $h_1 P_1 h_1^{-1} \neq h_2 P_1 h_2^{-1}$ for every $h_1, h_2 \in Q$).

Is this right?

Comment: Yeah. By Sylow's theorem I know there is $g \in G$ such that $g P_1 g^{-1} = P_2$. But how can I show that there is some $g \in Q$ ??

Comment: I think the second question is related to the first one.

Comment: Since $P_1\cap Q=1$, $G$ is the union of $qP_1$ where $q\in Q$. So every element can be written as $qp$ for some $q\in Q,p\in P_1$.

Comment: Ok, but I don't see how this would help. Should I try use this for a) or b?

Comment: Try this for $b$. Concretly speaking, you've known that there exists $g$ s.t. $gP_1g^{-1}=P_2$. Then you can write $g=qp$. After that, $p$ can be absorbed in $P_1$.

Comment: Ohh. So we have $q p P_1 p^{-1} q = P_2 $ . From $| P_1 | = p$, p prime, we have that $P_1$ is cyclic then abelian, so $q P_1 q^{-1} =  q p P_1 p^{-1} q = P_2 $. Right? Thank you!!

Comment: You are right but it's not so complicated. For $h\in H$ we always have $hHh^{-1}=H$, no matter whether $H$ is abelian or some other conditions.